# Using grammar from a .grammar file with ruby

Tags: ruby, grammar, snmp, mib

Looking for a way to parse SNMP Mib Files in Ruby, I found a project written in Java ([www.mibble.org](http://www.mibble.org)) that use two files of Grammar (extension .grammar) to parser Mib files. Is there any way to use grammar files with ruby?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/hallidave/ruby-snmp.

Comment: I need parse MIB file. This project use smidump tool to parse and export mib file to yaml file. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://grammatica.percederberg.net

If you dig further you will see the grammar file is for Grammatica, which only supports Java and C#.

Either you extend Grammatica to support Ruby or you will have to switch to other approaches. Note that Mibble is released GPL and a commercial license. If you are going to reuse the grammar file, make sure you meet the licensing requirements.

Our open source project, http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com uses ANTLR 3 to parse MIB documents. The grammar file is released under BSD 3 Clause. As ANTLR does support Ruby, http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3RubyTarget, you might reuse our MIB grammar.

Comment: Or you could just go for jruby and talk to the Java API.